# If I leap off my running mount onto an enemy, what happens?

Tags: dnd-5e, mounted-combat

I'm currently a half-orc dire wolf rider. Let's say I dash with my mount and upon reaching the enemy, I leap off my dire Wolf and attack with my Lance as I barrel into him.

Would I :

1. Knock him prone
2. Knock him prone while dealing damage of the Lance
3. Need to make an acrobatics check
4. Still make the athletics check to see if I knock him prone

Also, if I leave my Lance in the body(like dropping it) and use my bonus action to draw my longsword, since I have extra attack,  can I still attack with the longsword?

Comment: Are you asking about the rules as written? Or are you asking how you as the DM should adjudicate such a situation?

Comment: i guess i should go with RAW first

Comment: Also, you should ask the latter question as a separate question.

Comment: Ok mate, i will open a new one

Answer (score 8):

> Would I :
>
> 1. Knock him prone

If you take the Attack action and chose to Shove the creature (PHB pp.195-196): yes.

> 2. Knock him prone while dealing damage of the Lance

If you take the Attack action and are a Battle Master Fighter with the Trip Attack maneuver (PHB p.74) and spend a superiority die: yes.

> 3. Need to make an acrobatics check

No, dismounting simply costs half your speed (PHB p.198).

> 4. Still make the athletics check to see if I knock him prone

Not applicable.

> Also, if I leave my Lance in the body(like dropping it) and use my bonus action to draw my longsword, since I have extra attack, can I still attack with the longsword?

Yes but no. You can use the Extra Attack feature to make a subsequent attack using your *free* object interaction to draw the longsword. This doesn't use your bonus action and your bonus action can't be used to interact with an object anyway.

Comment: The Trip Attack maneuver would also necessitate using the Attack action

Comment: While this is given in the rules I am not sure it is the intention of the question. Leaping heroically off the mount vs dismounting. I don't think there is a better answer however.

Comment: @SeriousBri the OP is free to describe his actions any way he wants

Answer (score 3):

The long and short of it as per RAW is that leaping off your mount does not grant you any special benefit. If anything, the DM could rule that you have to make an athletics or acrobatics* check because you are not simply dismounting; you are leaping. In other words, as per RAW, this will either have no special effect or it will actually hinder you.

*Note that I gave the option of either athletics or acrobatics because it really depends on whether the DM is more focused on you executing the jump successfully or on you landing successfully, respectively.

Now, as far as house rules are concerned, any of your proposed outcomes are plausible. Personally, if one of my players attempted this, I would combine your answers and have this scenario:

- Lance damage as normal
- Free Shove attempt with advantage on the athletics check
- Acrobatics check to remain standing after attack

In the end, you have to understand that most things that "look cool", but fall outside the scope of written rules and standard actions are typically punished as per the RAW. It is rare that you can do something that isn't a codified action and actually be rewarded for it unless your DM house rules it so (which I do because I cherish ingenuity, originality, and style). If your DM doesn't typically play this way, stick to the standard actions and the actions of your class unless you're willing to take a penalty for style.

Answer (score 2):

[Here are the rules on Mounted Combat.](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Combat#toc_61)

First of all, half-orcs (and other Medium creatures) can't mount regular wolves (or other Medium creatures):

> A willing creature that is **at least one size larger than you** and that has an appropriate anatomy can serve as a mount, using the following rules.

A wolf is a Medium creature. A Dire Wolf or Winter Wolf could serve as a mount (assuming you managed to tame it), as they are both Large.  (Half-Orcs, like most player races, are Medium.)

Secondly, here are the only rules on dismounting a creature:

> Once during your move, you can mount a creature that is within 5 feet of you or dismount. Doing so costs an amount of movement equal to half your speed. For example, if your speed is 30 feet, you must spend 15 feet of movement to mount a horse. Therefore, you can’t mount it if you don’t have 15 feet of movement left or if your speed is 0.
>
> If an effect moves your mount against its will while you’re on it, you must succeed on a DC 10 Dexterity saving throw or fall off the mount, landing prone in a space within 5 feet of it. If you’re knocked prone while mounted, you must make the same saving throw.
>
> If your mount is knocked prone, you can use your reaction to dismount it as it falls and land on your feet. Otherwise, you are dismounted and fall prone in a space within 5 feet it.

There are no rules for combining a dismount with an attack. Your DM could house-rule otherwise, but there's no inherent benefit to dismounting as you attack by the rules as written.

> Also, if I leave my Lance in the body (like dropping it) and use my bonus action to draw my longsword, since I have extra attack, can I still attack with the longsword?

If you are of a class that has the Extra Attack feature and are high enough level to make multiple attacks as part of your Attack action, then this would be possible. You would have to make your first attack with an already-drawn lance (note that if you attack with a lance, you do so at disadvantage if the target is within 5 feet of you), drop/let go of the lance, use your free object interaction for the turn (not a bonus action) to draw the longsword, and then attack with it.

[This Sage Advice confirms that you can use different weapons for the multiple attacks granted by the Extra Attack feature](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/01/30/if-wielding-a-sword-in-each-hand-can-you-decide-what-to-main-action-attack/), as does [this one](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/12/05/extra-attack/). It's also confirmed in the [Sage Advice Compendium](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf):

> **When you use Extra Attack, do you have to use the same weapon for all the attacks?**
>
> Extra Attack imposes no limitation on what you use for the attacks. You can use regular weapons, improvised weapons, unarmed strikes, or a combination of these options for the attacks.

Comment: Yes, it's a dire wold, sorry i didn't add that in. Also, i was thinking more of it being a leap attack rather than a normal attack.

Comment: @CuriosMaximus: There are no special rules described for "leap attacks" in 5e.